# what is the optimal Multithreading scenario for processing a long file lines?

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, io

I have a big file and i want to read and also [process] all lines (even lines) of the file with multi threads.

One suggests to read the whole file and break it to multiple files (same count as threads), then let every thread process a specific file. as this idea will read the whole file, write it again and read multiple files it seems to be slow (3x I/O) and i think there must be better scenarios,

I myself though this could be a better scenario:

One thread will read the file and put the data on a global variable and other threads will read the data from that variable and process. more detailed:

One thread will read the main file with running `func1` function and put each even line on a Buffer: `line1Buffer` of a max size `MAX_BUFFER_SIZE` and other threads will pop their data from the Buffer and process it with running `func2` function. in code:

Global variables:

```
#define MAX_BUFFER_SIZE 100
vector<string> line1Buffer;
bool continue = true;// to end thread 2 to last thread by setting to false
string file = "reads.fq";
```

Function `func1` : (thread 1)

```
void func1(){
 ifstream ifstr(file.c_str());
 for (long long i = 0; i < numberOfReads; i++) { // 2 lines per read
    getline(ifstr,ReadSeq);
    getline(ifstr,ReadSeq);// reading even lines
    while( line1Buffer.size() == MAX_BUFFER_SIZE )
        ; // to delay when the buffer is full
    line1Buffer.push_back(ReadSeq);
 }
 continue = false;
 return;
}
```

And function `func2` : (other threads)

```
void func2(){
 string ReadSeq;
 while(continue){
    if(line2Buffer.size() > 0 ){
        ReadSeq  = line1Buffer.pop_back();
        // do the proccessing....
    }
 }
}
```

About the speed:

If the reading part is slower so the total time will be equal to reading the file for just one time(and the buffer may just contain 1 file at each time and hence just 1 another thread will be able to work with thread 1). and if the processing part is slower then the total time will be equal to the time for the whole processing with `numberOfThreads - 1` threads. both cases is faster than reading the file and writing in multiple files with 1 thread and then read the files with multi threads and process...

and so there is 2 question:

1- how to call the functions by threads the way thread 1 runs `func1` and others run `func2` ?

2- is there any faster scenario?

3-[Deleted] anyone can extend this idea to M threads for reading and N threads for processing? obviously we know :`M+N==umberOfThreads` is true

Edit: the 3rd question is not right as multiple threads can't help in reading a single file

Thanks All

Comment: @Hayt are you talking about question #3? yeah this won't help but if i use 1 thread reading the file and others for processing the content, then i think it will help, not right?

Comment: this depends on how much work the processing is. Your approach may work but you need to be careful that you have syncronization (mutexes). If the overhead of those is more than the actual processing than a multithreaded approach may be not needed here. Multiple reading would only be good if you can read in parallel (not sure if some RAIDs support that nicely though)

Comment: What's your OS?  What hardware are you running on, including disks and disk controllers?  C++ IO may not be the fastest way to process data - it abstracts away the underlying hardware design, and you can't drive hardware at its design limits if you abstract away those limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An other approach could be interleaved thread.
Reading is done by every thread, but only 1 at once.
Because of the waiting in the very first iteration, the 
threads will be interleaved.

But this is only an scaleable option, if `work()` is the bottleneck
(then every non-parallel execution would be better)

Thread:

```
while (!end) {
    // should be fair!
    lock();
    read();
    unlock();

    work();
}
```

basic example: (you should probably add some error-handling)

```
void thread_exec(ifstream* file,std::mutex* mutex,int* global_line_counter) {
    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::string> data;
    int i;
    do {
        i = 0;
        // only 1 concurrent reader
        mutex->lock();
        // try to read the maximum number of lines
        while(i < MAX_NUMBER_OF_LINES_PER_ITERATION && getline(*file,line)) {
            // only the even lines we want to process
            if (*global_line_counter % 2 == 0) {
                data.push_back(line);
                i++;
            }
            (*global_line_counter)++;

        }
        mutex->unlock();

        // execute work for every line
        for (int j=0; j < data.size(); j++) {
            work(data[j]);
        }

        // free old data
        data.clear();
     //until EOF was not reached
   } while(i == MAX_NUMBER_OF_LINES_PER_ITERATION);

}

void process_data(std::string file) {
     // counter for checking if line is even
     int global_line_counter = 0;
     // open file
     ifstream ifstr(file.c_str());
     // mutex for synchronization
     // maybe a fair-lock would be a better solution
     std::mutex mutex;
     // create threads and start them with thread_exec(&ifstr, &mutex, &global_line_counter);
     std::vector<std::thread> threads(NUM_THREADS);
     for (int i=0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
         threads[i] = std::thread(thread_exec, &ifstr, &mutex, &global_line_counter);
     }
     // wait until all threads have finished
     for (int i=0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
         threads[i].join();
     }
}
```

Comment: sounds good, could you put the code for calling mult threads in your answer and also the code for calling multithreads for my idea? and then i will accept it as the main answer, thanks

Comment: what do you mean with calling mult threads and calling multithreads?

Comment: i mean please write the main function to call the functions in multithread manner

Comment: I already did.  just call `process_data("reads.fq");` in the main function

Answer (score 1):

What is your bottleneck?  Hard disk or processing time?

If it's the hard disk, then you're probably not going to get any more performance out as you've hit the limits of the hardware.  Concurrent reads are by far faster than trying to jump around the file.  Having multiple threads trying to read your file will almost certainly reduce the overall speed as it will increase disk thrashing.

A single thread reading the file and a thread pool (or just 1 other thread) to deal with the contents is probably as good as you can get.

> Global variables:

This is a bad habit to get into.

Comment: no limitation on hard disk. but why you ask about hard disk limitation? i think that the idea of using 1 thread to read the file and others to process the content will be better in both hard disk usage and performance, not right?

Comment: Correct, (although the OS & disk will probably buffer the data for you anyway, even if you don't read it immediately) but it doesn't continue to scale.  If you have multiple threads reading the disk your performance will start to suffer.

Comment: you're right so i have to forget the 3rd question as it wont help :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assume having `#p` treads, two scenarios mentioned in the post and answers:

1) Reading with 'a' thread and processing with other threads, in this case `#p-1` thread will process in comparison with only one thread reading. assume the time for full operation is jobTime and time for processing with n threads is pTime(n) so:

worst case occurs when reading time is very slower than processing and  `jobTime = pTime(1)+readTime` and the best case is when the processing is slower than reading in which `jobTime` is equal to `pTime(#p-1)+readTime`

2) read and process with all `#p` threads. in this scenario every thread needs to do two steps. first step is to read a part of the file with size `MAX_BUFFER_SIZE` which is sequential; means no two threads can read at one time. but the second part is processing the read data which can be parallel. this way in the worst case `jobTime` is `pTime(1)+readTime` as before (but*), but the best optimized case is pTime(#p)+readTime which is better than previous.

*: in 2nd approach's worst case, however reading is slower but you can find a optimized `MAX_BUFFER_SIZE` in which (in the worst case) some reading with one thread will overlaps with some processing with another thread. with this optimized `MAX_BUFFER_SIZE` the `jobTime` will be less than `pTime(1)+readTime` and could diverge to `readTime`

Comment: could you please complete the answer of @Domso so i can accept that ?

Answer (score 0):

First off, reading a file is a slow operation so unless you are doing some superheavy processing, the file reading will be limiting.

If you do decide to go the multithreaded route a queue is the right approach. Just make sure you push in front an pop out back. An stl::deque should work well. Also you will need to lock the queue with a mutex and sychronize it with a conditional variable.

One last thing is you will need to limit the size if the queue for the scenario where we are pushing faster than we are popping.

Comment: yeah i used MAX_BUFFER_SIZE , why not using stl::vector and push and pop from back of the vector ? and what you mean by "synchronize it with a conditional variable" ?